# using the induction technique to prove $\Pi_{i=1}^{k}(2i-1)=\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)2^k}$

Tags: induction

$\Pi_{i=1}^{k}(2i-1)=\frac{(2k)!}{k!2^k}$

clearly the products are in the set of the natural numbers.

Step one show that P(1) is true

$2(1)-1=1$

True.

Step 2 induction assumption

$\Pi_{i=1}^{k}(2i-1)=\frac{(2k)!}{k!2^k}$

This is what we assume to be true.

**Step 3**

$P(k+1)$

$\Pi_{i=1}^{k+1}(2i-1)=\frac{(2k+1)!}{(k+1)!2^{k+1}}$

The right hand side can be reduced to $\frac{2}{2^k2}$

$\Pi_{i=1}^{k+1}(2i-1)=2(k+1) + \Pi_{i=1}^{k}(2i-1)$

which is the last product times the multiplication of all the previous products.

$=2k+1 + \frac{(2k)!}{k!2^k}$

$=\frac{(2k+1)(2k)!}{k!2^k}$

$=\frac{2k+1(2)}{2^k}$

I am not sure how to continue this proof.

Comment: You misparsed. The right hand side is $$\frac{(2k)!}{2^k(k!)}.$$

Comment: Yes I shall edit

Comment: hmm so I reduced incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\prod_{k=1}^{n+1}(2k-1)=(2(n+1)-1)\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)=(2n+1)\frac{(2n)!}{n!2^{n}}=\frac{(2(n+1))!}{2(n+1)n!2^{n}}=\frac{(2(n+1))!}{(n+1)!2^{n+1}}$

Comment: I see so the right hand side cannot be reduced to $\frac{2}{2^k(2)}$ by factoring out 2

Comment: No it cannot. $\frac{(2n)!}{n!}\neq2$. It may be helpful to see an example. Take $n=2$ then $\frac{4!}{2!}=4\cdot3=12$.

Answer (score 1):

Wy do you need an induction for this? It's an overkill. Instead:
$$
1 \cdot 3 \ldots (2n-1) = \frac{1 \cdot 2 \ldots 2n}{2 \cdot 4 \ldots 2n} =\frac{(2n)!}{2 \cdot (2 \cdot 2) \cdot (2 \cdot 3) \ldots (2 \cdot n)} = \frac{(2n)!}{n! 2^n}
$$
The last step is because you have $n$ terms in the denominator.